# How to make a color changing sky in Racket?

Tags: racket

I have a variable that controls the number of blue in (color R, G, B). Now I am confused about how to use that variable in (color R, G, B). Also, I am totally new to Racket. I know I can combine these functions together, but I don't know how :( The purpose of this code is to make a color changing scene in animate.
Here is my code:

(require 2htdp/image)

(define(Skycolor num)
(remainder num 510))

(define(skycolor num)
(abs(- 255(Skycolor num))))

(define(sky-color num)
(color 0 0 (skycolor num)))

(define (SKY num )
(square 200 "solid" (color 0 0 (sky-color num)))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what do you mean with "color changing", but you can take some inspiration from following code. See also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72205143/racket-beginner-student-language-confusion), where I explain how [`animate`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpuniverse.html#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Funiverse..rkt%29._animate%29%29) works.

```
#lang racket

(require 2htdp/universe)
(require 2htdp/image)

(define speed 5)

(define (sky-color ticks)
  (color 0 (modulo (* speed (- 255 ticks)) 255) 255))

(define bg
  (empty-scene 125 125))

(define (make-sky ticks)
  (square 250 "solid" (sky-color ticks)))

(define (draw-image ticks)
  (place-image (make-sky ticks) 0 0 bg))

(animate draw-image)
```